# Why doesn't my jasperserver allow me to upload an image (or any "file") to the repository?

Tags: java, tomcat, jasperserver

I just setup a fresh install of tomcat and jasper server. For some reason when I right click and select "Add Resource" to add a new image to the repository it doesn't give me "File" as and option so I can not. I have jasper server running on two other servers and the "Add Resource" -> "File" -> "Image" appears as it should. Has anyone else had this problem or know what's wrong with the new setup? I can't seem to find anywhere to enable the "File" resource.

Comment: Did you check log files?

Comment: Big Tuna, did you get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah... that's an embarrassing bug, eh? Take a look at the file .../WEB-INF/actionModel-search.xml. You'll find this snippet around line 21:

```
<selectAction labelKey="RM_NEW_RESOURCE_FILE" className="flyout"
                        clientTest="canResourceBeCreated" clientTestArgs="FileResource" >
```

That code should not be surrounded by this:

```
<condition test="isProVersion">...</condition>
```

But it **is** surrounded by that. Doh. You can probably figure out how to modify it manually now that you know what to look for. Or you could grab an old copy of that file from your working machines to see how it should be. Or you can wait for the next release when it's back to working as it should. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the condition tags where the selectAction tags are enclosed in, as suggested by mdahlman, not the tags inside selectAction:

```
**<!-- 
    <condition test="isProVersion">
        <condition test="isSupportedDevice">
            <option labelKey="RM_NEW_DOMAIN" action="invokeCreate" actionArgs="SemanticLayerDataSource" clientTest="canResourceBeCreated" clientTestArgs="SemanticLayerDataSource" className="up"/>
        </condition>
-->**

        <selectAction labelKey="RM_NEW_RESOURCE_FILE" className="flyout" clientTest="canResourceBeCreated" clientTestArgs="FileResource" >

         ...

        </selectAction>
**<!-- 
    </condition>
 -->**
```